# How to dynamically combine generators?

Tags: iterator, generator, python-itertools, reddit, praw

```
for submissions in itertools.zip_longest(submission_stream, submission_stream2): #want to put all streams here
            for submission in submissions:
                # processing
```

The above code works for two streams that I have initialised. My goal is to combine streams based on username in a .csv file. If a username is there, run a stream for them. If it gets removed, or a new username is added, remove or start that stream respectively.
An example of a stream is:

```
submission_stream = reddit.redditor("username").stream.submissions(skip_existing=True, pause_after=-1)
```

I would really appreciate if someone would guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to start streaming over again every time your `.csv` file is changed, although you could get away with filtering (`itertools.filterfalse`)
for username removals. Code sketch, assuming functions to get a list of streams, determine if a submission belongs to deleted username, and determine if file was changed with an addition:

```
while True:
    streams = get_list_of_streams_from_csv()
    for submissions in itertools.zip_longest(streams):
        for submission in itertools.filterfalse(not_deleted, submissions):
            #processing
        if csv_changed_to_add()
            break
```

Adding in additional streams, capturing deletion with `.filterfalse`:

```
streams = get_list_of_streams_from_csv()
zip_iter = itertools.zip_longest(streams)
while True:
    for submission in itertools.filterfalse(not_deleted, zip_iter):
        #processing
        if csv_changed_to_add()
            break    
    zip_iter = itertools.zip_longest(zip_iter, get_list_of_new_streams())
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way to do it without stopping the stream, as it's crucial not to miss anything. Would perhaps appending to the streams list in-place work?

Comment: There might be a way to tie in new streams. See update to answer.